# override overflow:hidden with z-index

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

Am using coda_bubble jquery plugin, and i need to make my bubble pop out within an overflow hidden div. here is my sample code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Override overflow:hidden</title>
<link href="http://www.myjquery.co.uk/jslib/jquery_plugins/coda_bubble/bubble.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myjquery.co.uk/jslib/jquery_plugins/coda_bubble/jquery.codabubble.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   opts = {
      distances : [40,40],
      leftShifts : [0,0],
      bubbleTimes : [400,400],
      hideDelays : [0,0],
      bubbleWidths : [200,200],
      bubbleImagesPath : "YOUR RELATIVE PATH TO SKIN FOLDER",
      msieFix : true
   };
   $('.coda_bubble').codaBubble(opts);
});
</script> 
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#wrapper{
    width:300px;
    margin:200px auto;
    }
.overflow{
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    }
.coda_bubble{
    z-index:100;/****NOT WORKING*******/
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="overflow">
       <div class="coda_bubble">
            <div>
                <p class="trigger">Trigger Bubble</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubble_html">
               [BUBBLE CONTENT]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overflow" style="overflow: visible;">
       <div class="coda_bubble">
            <div>
                <p class="trigger">Trigger Bubble</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubble_html">
               [BUBBLE CONTENT]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't need .coda_bubble to be a child of .overflow. If not then move it out and create a positioning div to hold both children.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Override overflow:hidden</title>
<link href="http://www.myjquery.co.uk/jslib/jquery_plugins/coda_bubble/bubble.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myjquery.co.uk/jslib/jquery_plugins/coda_bubble/jquery.codabubble.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   opts = {
      distances : [40,40],
      leftShifts : [0,0],
      bubbleTimes : [400,400],
      hideDelays : [0,0],
      bubbleWidths : [200,200],
      bubbleImagesPath : "YOUR RELATIVE PATH TO SKIN FOLDER",
      msieFix : true
   };
   $('.coda_bubble').codaBubble(opts);
});
</script> 
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#wrapper{
    width:300px;
    margin:200px auto;
    }
.overflow{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute; /*May not be needed.*/
    }
.position {
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
}
.coda_bubble{
    /*z-index:100;/****NOT WORKING*******/
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="position">
        <div class="overflow">
           [overflow content]
        </div>
        <div class="coda_bubble">
            <div>
                <p class="trigger">Trigger Bubble</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubble_html">
               [BUBBLE CONTENT]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="position">
        <div class="overflow" style="overflow:">
           [overflow content]
        </div>
        <div class="coda_bubble">
            <div>
                <p class="trigger">Trigger Bubble</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubble_html">
               [BUBBLE CONTENT]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx Byran, the idea is great, let me try it that.

Answer (score 25):

I would calculate the offset position from the window, remove it from its parent and attach it to the body.

Eg:

```
var left, top;
left = jQuery(element).offset().left;
top = jQuery(element).offset().top;
jQuery(element)
  .appendTo('body')
  .css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': left + 'px',
    'top': top + 'px'
  });
```

Answer (score 19):

You can't.
overflow: hidden; Hides content outside the element. Period.

z-index applies to absolute AND relatively positioned elements, just differently, despite what someone else said.

*EDIT*
You could put some padding-top on that particular div, if you can live with that padding, that is. The div would need to be a little wider, too.

*EDIT 2*
As others have stated, though position: relative; and position: absolute; are probably more common, yes, z-index works with position: fixed; also, just not for position: static; I overlooked those.

Answer (score 8):

Just a correction: `z-index` applies to `position: relative`, `position:absolute` AND `position:fixed`.
To answer the original question - there's no way in CSS to make a child of an `overflow: hidden` element show it's contents outside the parent borders, you must change the hierarchy.

Comment: It would be so much better if it were possible to have the children overwrite some of its forfathers settings, just for themselves. Then some of the children of an overflow-hidden div could be visible (such as shades of elements inside it), but the rest would remain as is. This restriction literally forces developers to turn their solution into a hack.

Comment: The hierarchy of HTML and CSS forces many of these antipatterns, it takes a great deal of experience doing complicated layouts in an optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` property **ONLY** work in elements that have `position` option set to `absolute` or `relative`.

In other words you **ALWAYS** need `positon` to work with `z-index`.

Answer (score -1):

The z-index property applies to those elements having position set to absolute. Try this css instead:

```
.coda_bubble{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;/****NOT WORKING*******/
}
```

Comment: Thanx Sharfraz, but still the bubble is hidden.

.overflow{
    width:120px;
    height:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
 position:relative;
    }
.coda_bubble{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;/****NOT WORKING*******/
    }

Comment: remove the .overflow class from element to check what happens.

Comment: Just a Note: z-index requires any positioning other than static.