# Impossible to bleed nested div when container is positioned relative and has overflow hidden?

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, html

I wonder whether it's totally impossible to bleed a nested div when the container is positioned relative and has overflow set to hidden?

Giving the nested div a fixed position is not an alternative in this case.

Please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/s7nhw/11/.

Anyone who knows how to do this?

I'll appreciate any feedback!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="nested-div"></div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.nested-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;

    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Comment: 1) what do you exactly mean with "bleed"? 2) your nested div is in absolute position, not fixed 3) what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan 1) Bleed = Overflow 2) It has to be in my case 3) I could solve my issue (which is not explained here) otherwise, but just curious to see if this is actually possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute position child elements always remain under relative position parent element

Answer (score 1):

I've never encountered a situation where one could override {overflow: hidden}. You'll probably need to restructure your HTML to place the nested div outside its parent in the code, then use absolute positioning and z-index to position it behind the current wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/s7nhw/13

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
.nested-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

<div class="nested-div"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Here's some further discussion: [override overflow:hidden with z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952344/override-overflowhidden-with-z-index)

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but in my case, I cannot move the nested-div outside the container and use absolute positioning.
It's totally possible to override {overflow:hidden} - just remove {position:relative} and u'll see. @isherwood

Comment: Thx for trying! But u set the container position to static - it has to be relative. @isherwood

Comment: Oh, right. I got lost for a minute there. In that case, my original answer stands.

Comment: The example does not work, but I believe you are trying to move the nested-div outside the container and position it absolute, which works, but in that case, the nested-div will not be nested anymore.

Comment: @Chris, I said as much in the answer.